# .AsNoTracking() is not working for Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a Repository code as below:

```
public async Task<List<RedeProduto>> InserirRedeProduto(int idRede, int idLoja, List<NomeProdutoScore> nomeProdutosScore)
        {
            IEnumerable<NomeProdutoScore> produtosInternosAInserir = new List<NomeProdutoScore>();
            List<NomeProdutoScore> produtosInternosAInserirLista = new List<NomeProdutoScore>();

            try
            {
                var redesProdutos = _v1Context.RedesProdutos
                .Where(r => r.IdRede == idRede && r.IdLoja == idLoja)
                .AsNoTracking();

                produtosInternosAInserir = nomeProdutosScore
                    .Where(np => !redesProdutos.Any(rp => rp.SkuRede == np.CodigoBarraNormalizar));
   
                produtosInternosAInserirLista = produtosInternosAInserir
                    .Where(p => p.ScoreFinal == 1)
                    .ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

            List<RedeProduto> redesProdutosAInserir = new List<RedeProduto>();

            try
            {
                if (produtosInternosAInserirLista.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (NomeProdutoScore produtoInternoAInserir in produtosInternosAInserirLista)
                    {
                        RedeProduto redeProduto = new RedeProduto();

                        redeProduto.IdRede = idRede;
                        redeProduto.IdProduto = produtoInternoAInserir.IdProduto;
                        redeProduto.SkuRede = produtoInternoAInserir.CodigoBarraNormalizar;
                        redeProduto.IdLoja = idLoja;
                        redeProduto.Auto = true;
                        redeProduto.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
                        redeProduto.AutoTipo = "SCO";

                        redesProdutosAInserir.Add(redeProduto);
                    }

                    await _v1Context.AddRangeAsync(redesProdutosAInserir);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
     
            return redesProdutosAInserir;
        }
```

As you see, .AsNoTracking() is applied to doesn´t track the entity "RedesProdutos".

I have a Unit Test as below:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task InserirRedeProduto_IdRedeEIdLojaENomeProdutosScore_RedeProdutosAInserir()
        {
            // Arrange

            var dbV1Context = (V1Context)DbFactory.Criar(DbFactory.Bancos.V1_IN_MEMORY);
            var dbIntegracaoContext = (IntegracaoContext)DbFactory.Criar(DbFactory.Bancos.INTEGRACAO_IN_MEMORY);

            int idRede = 1;

            int idLoja = 1;

            List<NomeProdutoScore> nomeProdutosScore = new List<NomeProdutoScore>() { };

            NomeProdutoScore nomeProdutoScore = new()
            {
                Normalizado = "ABACATE VERDE MADURO",
                IdProduto = 1,
                ImageUrl = "www",
                Normalizar = "ABACATE VERDE MADURO",
                CodigoBarraNormalizar = "0001",
                PosicaoRank = 1000,
                QuantidadePalavrasComparacao = 3,
                QuantidadePalavrasComparacaoEncontradas = 3,
                QuantidadePalavrasComparacaoNokEncontradas = 0,
                ScoreMatch = 1,
                ScoreFinal = 1,
                FatorReducao = 1,
                PesoVariavel = true,
                QuantidadeDias = 1
            };

            nomeProdutosScore.Add(nomeProdutoScore);

            dbV1Context.RedesProdutos.Add(new RedeProduto
            {
                IdRede = 1,
                IdLoja = 1,
                SkuRede = "0002"
            }
            );

            await dbV1Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            _lojaRepository = new LojaRepository(dbV1Context, dbIntegracaoContext);

            // Act

            List<RedeProduto> redesProdutosAInserir = await _lojaRepository.InserirRedeProduto(idRede, idLoja, nomeProdutosScore);

            // Assert

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Assert.Equal(idRede, redesProdutosAInserir[i].IdRede);
                Assert.Equal(nomeProdutoScore.IdProduto, redesProdutosAInserir[i].IdProduto);
                Assert.Equal(nomeProdutoScore.CodigoBarraNormalizar, redesProdutosAInserir[i].SkuRede);
                Assert.Equal(idLoja, redesProdutosAInserir[i].IdLoja);
                Assert.True(redesProdutosAInserir[i].Auto);
                Assert.InRange(redesProdutosAInserir[i].DataCadastro, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10), DateTime.Now);
                Assert.Contains("SCO", redesProdutosAInserir[i].AutoTipo);
            }
        }
```

I use InMemory DB to don´t use the DB directly. But, I am having this error message during the Unit Test: "System.Exception : The instance of entity type 'RedeProduto' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdRede'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values".

During the Integration Test, using directly the DB, .AsNoTracking() works fine. But in the Unit Test, I receive this error message. It seems that .AsNoTracking() it´s not working well. Any ideas?

The error is throw in this line:

```
await _v1Context.AddRangeAsync(redesProdutosAInserir);
```

Comment: Have you followed the advice given in the error message?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of this unit test?  What things that could go wrong are you trying to identify?

Comment: The conflict is based in the RedeProduto id, that is IdRede. I have in this test two entities RedeProduto. But for the first one is applied the .AsNoTracking(). So, I believe, that shouldn´t track this one, and the second that is create in the Repository code should pass the Update.

Comment: Yes, I know it is also not answering the question but there is not much point testing against an in-memory database since this is not what you are using in production and does not behave the same way as SQL. Microsoft were talking about ditching it because it has limited value. A unit test should test a single unit of code i.e. a single method.

Comment: I does this. It is A Unit Test.

Comment: Actually, it´s an Insert.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When a record is updated I need to update an UpdatedTimestamp, when it's created it needs to update a CreatedTimestamp. This is repository logic that should be tested. To find out if it's an update or a create you have to get an item, which starts tracking if you don't use AsNoTracking, and it works when executed, but the unit test thinks the item is already being tracked, like AsNoTracking has no effect